# import requests in python error for non root user

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

im running "import requests" as non root user and its giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 108, in <module>
    from .__version__ import __title__, __description__, __url__, __version__
ImportError: No module named __version__
```

but i dont get that error when i try to import it as root. I'm assuming its a permission issue and I changed the permissions on

```
/lib/python2.7/site-packages/version-0.1.1-py2.7.egg-info/ 
and also on /lib/python2.7/site-packages/version.py
```

but that didnt solve my problems. any ideas?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240754/why-can-i-import-certain-modules-in-python-only-with-administrator-rights

Comment: _I'm assuming its a permission issue_ Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have problems with `/lib/python2.7/site-packages/version.py`, you have a problem with `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__version__.py`. Try to fix permissions on the file:

```
sudo chmod a+r /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__version__.py
```

or the entire package:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests
```

or may be the entire site-packages directory:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

And next time you do `sudo pip install` verify that your **root** `umask` is `022`:

```
sudo bash -c umask
```

If it's not either change it in `/root/.bashrc` or run `pip install` with the proper `umask`:

```
sudo bash -c "umask 022; pip install…"
```